# What does it mean by Big Brother?

Tags: privacy

While searching some sites, I came across this advt, looks like this:
They specifically mention **Big Brother is watching you**, so is he referring to our own government is spying on me? 
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Brother_(Nineteen_Eighty-Four)

Answer (score 6):

It's a name adopted from George Orwell's novel 1984 (published in 1949) where a  totalitarian state/entity named Big Brother has and seeks total power over everyone else. "Big Brother is watching you" is a phrase repeated to the citizens to remind them to be subservient. It is now used to describe any overly-controlling authority figure or abuse of authoritative power, especially mass surveillance.